# Collect custom object from list of custom objects where object val equals x

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm struggling to work out how to collect a custom object from a list of custom objects where an object value equals x using Java streams.

Consider I have the below class:

```
public class Person {

    private int age;
    private double height;

    public Person(int age, double height) {
        this.age= age;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Then consider that have a populated list of these objects e.g. `List<Person> people`.

My question is, how do I use streams to create a new `List<Person>` which contains only person objects which contain an age of say, 35, from that initial list?

What I have so far is the below:

```
List<Person> peopleAged35 = new ArrayList<>();
peopleAged35.add(people.stream().filter(i -> i.getAge() == 35).map(new Person).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

That doesn't compile but I don't think I'm far off - Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `.map(new Person)` from your stream.

Also, it's not strictly necessary to create a `new ArrayList` and add them to it; the Collectors.toList will return it for you anway -- although it will be read-only.

Comment: That doesn't look like it works, i get the below issue compile warning:

Required type:
Person

Provided:
List
<com.xxx.xxx.xxx.people.Person>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that List<T> conforms to Person

Comment: Try getting rid of the .add so it’s just List<People> over35 = people.stream()... the problem is that the add method is generic so it’s not sure what to make the return type. If you explicitly put it, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Person> aged35 = people.stream().filter(i -> i.getAge() == 35).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Not sure why you map to the new Person. If you need to get new objects instead of the references that are used in base list, you should probably clone object (and create method Person.clone() for that), like:

```
List<Person> aged35 = people.stream().filter(i -> i.getAge() == 35).map(Person::clone).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This also looks like a good answer and will consider - Thank you